# How to Get Last 1 year Log Stream From AWS Using Python

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to get last 1 year **logstream** name using python. I am using  **describe_log_streams** to get the logstream name . But its giving me all the logstream name that exist in the system which is causing huge runtime . So I was wondering if it's possible to get only last 1 year logstream name using python boto3.

**My Attempt**

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3


logGroupName = "myloggroup"

boto3.setup_default_session(region_name = "region_name") 
client = boto3.client('logs',aws_access_key_id='aws_access_key_id',aws_secret_access_key='aws_secret_access_key')

response = client.describe_log_streams(
    logGroupName=logGroupName,
    orderBy='LogStreamName',
    descending=True
)



while 'nextToken' in response:
    response =  client.describe_log_streams(
                logGroupName=logGroupName,
                orderBy='LogStreamName',
                descending=True,
              nextToken = response['nextToken'])
    print(response)
```